# How to use snapshotChanges() method to get both key value and filter the data?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm working on an Angular Firebase Project, where I need to filter my database as well get the key values. Currently I'm using **valueChanges()** method in my service code (*inside getUnreadBooks and getFavoriteBooks methods, as shown below*) to get the data and filter it. But it gives me key value as 'undefined', when I try to get key value inside my template file. I tried to go with **snapshotChanges()** method, but can't work around how to use it  to get key values along with filtering the data . Below are my Angular FirebaseService, home.component.ts (*in which I am injecting my service code*) and home.component.html (template file) Code respectively:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {

  books: Observable<any[]>;
  unreadBooks;
  favoriteBooks;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getBooks(){
        this.books = this.db.list('/books').valueChanges() as Observable<any[]>;
        return this.books;
    }       

  getFavoriteBooks(){
    this.favoriteBooks = this.db.list('/books').valueChanges() as Observable<any[]>;
    this.favoriteBooks = this.favoriteBooks.map(books => {
        const topRatedBooks = books.filter(item =>  item.rate>4);
        return topRatedBooks;
    })
    return this.favoriteBooks;
  }

  getUnreadBooks(){
    this.unreadBooks = this.db.list('/books').valueChanges() as Observable<any[]>;
    this.unreadBooks = this.unreadBooks.map(books => {
        const ub = books.filter(item => item.dateread == null);
        return ub;
    })
    return this.unreadBooks;
  }
}
```

Home.Component.ts file =>

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseService } from '../../services/firebase.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  //favorite Books
  favoriteBooks: any;
  unreadBooks: any;

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firebaseService.getFavoriteBooks()
        .subscribe(favBooks => {
            this.favoriteBooks = favBooks;
            console.log(this.favoriteBooks);
        })
    this.firebaseService.getUnreadBooks()
        .subscribe(ubBooks => {
            this.unreadBooks = ubBooks;
            console.log('Unread Books:', this.unreadBooks);
        })
  }

}
```

Home.component.html file =>

```
<mat-toolbar>
    My Top Rated Books
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-grid-list cols="3">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let book of favoriteBooks">
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>
                    <h4>{{book.title}}</h4>
                </mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <img mat-card-image src="{{book.imageUrl}}" alt="{{book.title}}">
            <mat-card-actions>
                <button mat-button mat-raised-button class="detailsButton" [routerLink]="['/book/'+book.$key]">
                    <i class="material-icons">visibility</i>Book Details</button>
                <button mat-button mat-raised-button class="editButton" [routerLink]="['/editbook/'+book.$key]">
                    <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>Edit Book</button>
            </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>     
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>

<mat-toolbar>
    Books I have not read yet
</mat-toolbar>
<mat-grid-list cols="3">
    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let book of unreadBooks">
        <mat-card>
            <mat-card-header>
                <mat-card-title>
                    <h4>{{book.title}}</h4>
                </mat-card-title>
            </mat-card-header>
            <img mat-card-image src="{{book.imageUrl}}" alt="{{book.title}}">
            <mat-card-actions>
                <button mat-button mat-raised-button class="detailsButton" [routerLink]="['/book/'+book.$key]">
                    <i class="material-icons">visibility</i>Book Details</button>
                <button mat-button mat-raised-button class="editButton" [routerLink]="['/editbook/'+book.$key]">
                    <i class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>Edit Book</button>
            </mat-card-actions>
        </mat-card>     
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: what you tried with `snapshotChanges()`?. check this example [app](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#deleting-the-entire-list)

Comment: I tried snapshotChanges() in getFavoriteBooks() method ( in FirebaseService File ) in place of valueChanges() to get the key values. But can't work around how to apply filter method inside, while using snapshotChanges(). I need to get my books filtered as well get the key values of the filtered books. How could I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Declare a function to add id to your Object :

```
documentToDomainObject = _ => {
    const object = _.payload.doc.data();
    object.id = _.payload.doc.id;
    return object;
}
```

And use it in your getBooks method :

```
getBooks(){
  this.books = this.db.list('/books').snapshotChanges()
  .pipe(map(actions => actions.map(this.documentToDomainObject)));

  return this.books;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But its giving me an error in '.pipe(map..)' part as:  "Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map' "

Comment: You need to import the rxjs operator map `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';`

Comment: Have imported the method already. In spite of that, error message appears: "Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map' "

Comment: Its definitely map and not Map. Did you add rxjs to your project ?

Comment: Thanks for getting back. Earlier I have imported the 'rxjs/add/operator/map' library, but now have imported ' map ' from 'rxjs/operators/map', as you suggested and this "cannot find 'map' " error message got disappeared. But the original problem still persists, I'm still getting the 'undefined' value for 'key'.

Comment: How could I work with this :   getFavoriteBooks(){
    this.favoriteBooks = this.db.list('/books').valueChanges() as Observable<any[]>;
    this.favoriteBooks = this.favoriteBooks.map(books => {
        const topRatedBooks = books.filter(item =>  item.rate>4);
        return topRatedBooks;
    })
    return this.favoriteBooks;
  }. I want to filter my books as well get key values of filtered books through this method. How could I do that?

Comment: getFavoriteBooks(){ 
return this.db.list('/books').snapshotChanges()
.pipe(map(actions => 
    actions.map(this.documentToDomainObject)
    .filter(item => item.rate>4)));
}

Comment: For newer package versions, it seems like the import should be `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators` instead of `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';` (as indicated by another answer here)

Answer (score 5):

In my case I solved it by importing rxjs operator map, combined by .pipe

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Example:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { IdeaService } from './app.service';

import { config } from './app.config';
import { Idea } from './app.model';
import {
  AngularFirestoreDocument,
  AngularFirestoreCollection
} from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
template: `
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let idea of ideas | async">
            <pre>{{ idea | json }}</pre>
        </li>
    </ul>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  public ideasCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Idea>;
  public ideas: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore, private ideaService: IdeaService) {
    this.ideasCollection = db.collection<Idea>(config.collection_endpoint);
    this.ideas = this.ideasCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(actions => {
          return actions.map(a => {
            const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Idea;
            const id = a.payload.doc.id;
            return { id, ...data };
          });
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to import the rxjs operator map 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';   // in rxjs 6 version

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you elaborate on your answer and provide a working code example?

Answer (score 1):

I imported this
`import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`
and this solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

This is with angular 9 and it's working fine.this is set up in the service.ts and get the data from particular .ts file and just normally reader the data into template

```
 getAll() {
    return this.database.list('/products').snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map( action => action
      .map(a => {
        const key = a.payload.key;
        const data = a.payload.val();
        return  data;
      })));
  }
```

particular .ts

```
constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
    this.products$ = this.productService.getAll();
   }
```

particular .html

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of products$ | async" >
    <td> {{ product.title }}</td>
    <td> {{ product.price }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.data.list('/expenseCategories').snapshotChanges().forEach(snapshot=> {
      snapshot.forEach(keys => {
        TransactionService.expenseCategories.push(keys.payload.key);
      })
    });
```

Comment: No need to add an additional loop, just use pipe and map operator as suggested, additional loops would decrease performance

Answer (score 0):

Simple and effective solution: You will get both id and data

Add it in your service file in header part

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

your getBooks method :

```
getBooks(){
   return this.books = this.db.list('/books').snapshotChanges()
     .pipe(map(action => action
                .map(a => {
                    let obj:any = a.payload.doc.data()
                    return {
                        ...obj,
                        id: a.payload.doc.id
                    };
                })
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Firebase docs, I see that you cannot get the key when using `valueChanges()`, you can only get it when using `snapshotChanges()`.

Building on Neelaka's answer, if you're using Angular 12 and the latest version of firebase,  if you have a form that uses the `(keyup)` event binding you can get the key and also filter like so:

In your `product.services.ts` file:

```js
  getAll(){
    return this.db.list('/products').snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
      return actions.map(a => {
        const key = a.payload.key;
        const data = a.payload.val();
        return {data, key};
      })
    }));
  }
```

In `admin-products.component.ts` file:

```js
export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnDestroy {

  products!: { title: string; }[] | any;
  filteredProducts!: any[];
  subscription: Subscription;


  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
    
    this.subscription = this.productService.getAll().subscribe(products => {
      this.filteredProducts = this.products = products; 
    });
    
   }

  filter(query: string){
    
    this.filteredProducts = (query) ? 
    this.products.filter((p: { data: {title:string}, key: string }) => p.data.title.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(query.toLocaleLowerCase())) : 
    this.products;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

In `admin-products.html`

```html
<br>
<p>
    <a routerLink="/admin/products/new" class="btn btn-primary">New Product</a>
</p>
<br>
<p>
  <input #query (keyup)="filter(query.value)" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
</p>
<br>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Title</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let p of filteredProducts">
        <td>{{ p.data.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ p.data.price }}</td>
        <td>
            <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/', p.key]">Edit</a> ✍️ 
        </td>
        <td>
            <a (click)="delete(p.key)" id="delete">Delete</a>  
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```