# Document is not deleting from firestore

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am using angularfire 2. I want to delete a collection from firestore by pressing a button. When i press a button console shows me a document was deleted but that document was still there. In firestore i have store a collection (users) and i have many documents i want to delete a specific document from the collection.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 
'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
templateUrl: 'app.component.html'
}) 
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
users: Observable<any[]>;


constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {


this.users = this.afs.collection('users').valueChanges();
}

ngOnInit() {
 this.usersCol = this.afs.collection('users');

 this.users = this.usersCol.snapshotChanges()
  .map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
      const data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
      const id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return { id, data };
    })
  })

}

 onDelete(userId)
  {
  this.afs.doc('users/'+userId).delete();


  }

  }
```

app.component.html

```
<div class="card-body">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>


            <th>Photo</th>
           <th>Name</th>
           <th>Email</th>
           <th>Rating</th>

              <th >delete</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let user of users | async">

            <td >
              {{user.photoUrl}}
            </td>
    <td>
                     {{user.userName}}

                   </td>
                   <td >
                     {{user.email}}
                   </td>
                   <td>

                   {{user.rating}}
                 </td>

                   <td>

                   {{user.id}}
                 </td>


                   <td>
                       <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"  
      (click)="onDelete(user.id)">delete</button>
                   </td>


  </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thankyou

Comment: Did you try this way : `this.afs.collection('users').doc(userId).delete();` ?

Comment: yes , but there is an error occur as **Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type string, but it was: undefined
    at new FirestoreError (error.js:140)**

Comment: I see, your `user.id` is undefined because the `.valueChanges()` don't get the id value. You must use `.snapshotChanges()` like explained in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132105/8945135

Comment: I used snapshot too and it will delete my document as well. But the problem is that , the content  in the document of firestore are not shown in the table app.

Comment: Like for example, in the table it will only show the button but not the name , email , photo and rating.

Comment: If you are using snapshotChanges(), can you please update your code. Also can you add a `{{user.id}}` in your table to check if the id correctly loaded.

Comment: i have updated my code. Yes the id is showing correctly in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You are initializing your users with two different values. Remove this line in your code :

```
this.users = this.afs.collection('users').valueChanges();
```

2- The returned object in the ngOnInit is an array like this {1: id, 2: user}.

You should return a User object instead :

```
this.users = this.usersCol.snapshotChanges()
  .map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
      let data = a.payload.doc.data() as User;
      data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
      return data;
    })
  })
```

By typing your code, you could avoid this kind of errors :

```
...
users: Observable<User[]>;
...
this.afs.collection<User>('users');
...
```